# install -y msodbcsql17' returned a non-zero code: 100 when install odbc in docker

Tags: docker, odbc

I have a docker container that install odbc17 as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=alpine18-install%2Cubuntu17-install%2Cdebian8-install%2Credhat7-13-install%2Crhel7-offline  that has been working for past month in Azure

```
RUN if ! [[ "16.04 18.04 20.04 21.04 21.10" == *"$(lsb_release -rs)"* ]]; \
then \
    echo "Ubuntu $(lsb_release -rs) is not currently supported."; \
    exit; \
fi

RUN sudo su
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gnupg2

RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -

RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/$(lsb_release -rs)/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

RUN exit
RUN sudo apt-get update
RUN sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17
```

But now it is failing with the return:

```
The command '/bin/sh -c sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

looking through the build trace, I see:

```
2023-02-14T11:24:14.9398390Z Preparing to unpack .../libodbc1_2.3.11_amd64.deb ...
2023-02-14T11:24:14.9410458Z Unpacking libodbc1:amd64 (2.3.11) ...
2023-02-14T11:24:14.9446555Z dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libodbc1_2.3.11_amd64.deb (--unpack):
2023-02-14T11:24:14.9448446Z  trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbc.so.2.0.0', which is also in package libodbc2:amd64 2.3.9-5
2023-02-14T11:24:14.9453201Z dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
2023-02-14T11:24:14.9600783Z Selecting previously unselected package odbcinst1debian2:amd64.
2023-02-14T11:24:14.9657111Z Preparing to unpack .../odbcinst1debian2_2.3.11_amd64.deb ...
2023-02-14T11:24:14.9670061Z Unpacking odbcinst1debian2:amd64 (2.3.11) ...
2023-02-14T11:24:14.9702481Z dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/odbcinst1debian2_2.3.11_amd64.deb (--unpack):
2023-02-14T11:24:14.9703365Z  trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbcinst.so.2.0.0', which is also in package libodbcinst2:amd64 2.3.9-5
2023-02-14T11:24:14.9712820Z dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
2023-02-14T11:24:14.9879447Z Selecting previously unselected package odbcinst.
2023-02-14T11:24:14.9879982Z Preparing to unpack .../odbcinst_2.3.11_amd64.deb ...
2023-02-14T11:24:14.9896590Z Unpacking odbcinst (2.3.11) ...
2023-02-14T11:24:14.9924471Z dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/odbcinst_2.3.11_amd64.deb (--unpack):
2023-02-14T11:24:14.9925203Z  trying to overwrite '/etc/odbc.ini', which is also in package unixodbc-common 2.3.9-5
2023-02-14T11:24:15.0031636Z Selecting previously unselected package unixodbc.
2023-02-14T11:24:15.0086839Z Preparing to unpack .../unixodbc_2.3.11_amd64.deb ...
2023-02-14T11:24:15.0099782Z Unpacking unixodbc (2.3.11) ...
2023-02-14T11:24:15.0345718Z Selecting previously unselected package msodbcsql17.
2023-02-14T11:24:15.0408910Z Preparing to unpack .../msodbcsql17_17.10.2.1-1_amd64.deb ...
2023-02-14T11:24:15.1308373Z debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
2023-02-14T11:24:15.1308981Z debconf: (Dialog frontend will not work on a dumb terminal, an emacs shell buffer, or without a controlling terminal.)
2023-02-14T11:24:15.1309532Z debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
2023-02-14T11:24:15.1900197Z Unpacking msodbcsql17 (17.10.2.1-1) ...
2023-02-14T11:24:15.2861152Z Errors were encountered while processing:
2023-02-14T11:24:15.2911953Z  /var/cache/apt/archives/libodbc1_2.3.11_amd64.deb
2023-02-14T11:24:15.2913469Z  /var/cache/apt/archives/odbcinst1debian2_2.3.11_amd64.deb
2023-02-14T11:24:15.2913914Z  /var/cache/apt/archives/odbcinst_2.3.11_amd64.deb
2023-02-14T11:24:15.3017753Z [91mW: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
2023-02-14T11:24:15.3019957Z W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
2023-02-14T11:24:15.3021244Z E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to overcome?

Comment: @frank- I would suggest review the similar issue [posted here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1180640/issue-install-msodbcsql17-on-docker) and request you add these lines of code in you docker file and retry the operation.

RUN sudo apt-get update && apt install -y apt-utils
RUN echo 'debconf debconf/frontend select Noninteractive' | debconf-set-selections
RUN sudo apt-get remove -y libodbc2 libodbcinst2 odbcinst unixodbc-common